# Use Javascript array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I know this question has been asked before several times on this forum, but I think I am missing something. Or maybe it is because I don't know JSON/AJAX that well.

Here is the thing.
I got some javascript/JQuery code on a page, say on index.php, (not yet in a seperate JS file) which let you put any number in an array from 1 to 10. If it's already in it, it will be removed if clicked again.

Now I want to pass that JS array to PHP, so I can create tables with it.

Here's what I have done.

```
$(".Go").click(function() {
    var enc = JSON.stringify(tableChoice);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'calc.php',
        data: {
            elements: enc
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(enc);
        }
    });
});
```

And in my calc.php I got this to get the values to PHP.

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode($_POST['elements'],true);
    echo $data;
?>
```

Now here comes the noob question:
If I click my (.Go) button, what really happens?
Because the console.log let's me see the correct values, but how do I access it? The page (index.php) doesn't automatically go to the calc.php.
When I use a `<form>` tag it will take me there, but it shows this error:

Undefined index: elements

I am sure I am looking at this the wrong way, interpreting it wrong.
Can someone please help me understand what it is I should be doing to continue with the JS array in PHP.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Ajax, or Asynchronous JavaScript and XML is a concept designed for interactive websites where data can be send to and collected from the server without the need to refresh the website. Your browser is not supposed to navigate to `calc.php`. Instead, `calc.php` echos the data back to your `index.php` file. `$data` however is an array here. So you won't get the actual value returned. Try `var_dump($data);` instead to see what I mean.

Comment: I think you need to read a tutorial on how AJAX works. The whole point of AJAX is that it doesn't reload the page. It just sends back the response, and the Javascript code decides what to do with it. If you want to display the result on the page, you use DOM or jQuery methods that do that, like `$("#id").text(data)`

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I got it to work now I understand the meaning behind it.

Answer (score 0):

With a XHR request you don't do a page reload. With your $.ajax method you post data to the server and receive information back. Since you can see information in your console, the success method is triggered.

You might want to take a look at your DevTools in for example Chrome. When you open your Network tab and filter on XHR you see what happens. You can inspect your XHR further by looking into the data you've send and received.

So my question to you is: what do you want to happen onSuccess()? What should happen with the data you receive from your backend?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```
$(".Go").click(function() {
    var enc = JSON.stringify(tableChoice);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'calc.php',
        data: {
            "elements="+enc;
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);// You can use the value of data to anywhere.
        }
    });
});
```

In PHP:

```
<?php
if(isSet($_POST[elements]))
{
    $data = json_decode($_POST['elements'],true);
    echo $data;
}
else
{
    echo "Elements not set";
}

?>
```